# I have multiple tables and I want to store file with data in 2 tables, How can I upload different files in different tables using AngularJs?

Tags: c#, angularjs

i am developing a web application in which i am adding two files in two different tables with data. data and files are not saving in SQL Db how i can add them?? My Angular js code is given below

```
$scope.addQuestionair = function () {
            var cID = document.getElementById("CustomerID").value;
            var pID = document.getElementById("ProjectID").value;

            $scope.question.CustomerID = cID;
            $scope.question.ProjectID = pID;

            console.info($scope.question);
            console.info($scope.OptionsList);

            var viewObj = {
                questionair: $scope.question,
                options: $scope.OptionsList
            };

            console.info(viewObj);

            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'api/Questions/AddQuestion',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined },
                uploadEventHandlers: {
                    progress: function (e) {
                        if (e.lengthComputable) {
                            var progressValue = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
                            $scope.ProgressWidth = 0;
                            $scope.ProgressWidth = { 'width': progressValue + '%' };
                        }
                    }
                },
                transformRequest: function (data) {
                    console.info("in transform");
                    var formData = new FormData();
                    formData.append("model", angular.toJson(data.model));
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.files.length; i++) {
                        formData.append(data.files[i].name, data.files[i]);
                    }
                    return formData;
                },
                data: { model: viewObj, files: $scope.files }
            }).then(function (response) {
                console.info(response);
                $scope.SaveMessage = response.data;
                GetQuestionair();
                $scope.question = null;
            }, function (error) {

            });
        };
```

how I can Add files in two different tables.

Comment: this is just your angular code... do you also have C# code to share? You are posting your data to an API, but the API code is what will actually be saving the data to the DB, so it would be helpful to include that here. Are you getting error messages when you post to the API? What exactly is the issue you need help with?

Comment: thanks coDe murDerer my  C# cose is given below my problem is that other data like fileds input are saving in db but file is not saving.

Comment: [HttpPost]
  public HttpResponseMessage AddQuestion()
  {
   if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
   {
    throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
   }

   HttpFileCollection hfc = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files;
   var model = HttpContext.Current.Request["model"];

Comment: ViewModel viewModel = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ViewModel>(model);
   if (viewModel == null)
   {
    throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
   }

   var root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/SiteImages/");

   if (!Directory.Exists(root))
   {
    Directory.CreateDirectory(root);
   }

   HttpPostedFile hpf = hfc[0];

   if (hpf.ContentLength > 0)
   { 
    hpf.SaveAs(root + "/" + Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName));
   }
   {
    db.Tbl_Questionair.Add(viewModel.questionair);
    db.SaveChanges();

Comment: foreach (var item in viewModel.options)
    {
     item.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
     item.QID = viewModel.questionair.ID;
     item.CustomerID = viewModel.questionair.CustomerID;
     item.ProjectID = viewModel.questionair.ProjectID;
     db.Options.Add(item);
     db.SaveChanges();
    }
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Data successfully saved!");
   }
  }